# Community Wiki Protocol?

Tags: support, community-wiki

This question [Which careers allow working in the wild on a daily basis?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1036/which-careers-allow-working-in-the-wild-on-a-daily-basis) seems like a good candidate for a Community Wiki: Lots of answers, no particular "right" answer... however the person who originally answered it should get some rep for effort...

What is the protocol for establishing a community wiki? Or is this doing it wrong?

Comment: +1 I would agree this is a wiki question if I ever saw one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about the purpose of community wiki [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

I think the question in this case is a reasonable candidate for CW and I've converted it to be a wiki. Ideally future answers should be edits on the existing comprehensive answer instead of additional separate answers.

Comment: I'm curious why the question was marked community wiki. The answer seems obviously geared to CW so that lots of people don't inflate the OA reputation, but is the community going to realistically be needed to shape the question as well? Is the purpose of CW to deprive the asker as well as the answerer of votes in this case?

Comment: @bmike Not inflating reputation is a side-effect of CW, not its primary purpose. Nor is it supposed to deprive anyone of votes. That said, I thought about it some more and removed wiki from the question. I hope that other users choose to edit the master answer instead of contributing their own, but managing that is up to you all as a community.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I have been around some several discussions trying to manage CW on the Ask Different site - so I agree it's important for the people who contribute here to form a consensus in the near term to help shape what looks like a CW to this forum.

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted the answer to the question, and I'm not bothered by whatever rep I might not get by making it a CW. Rep is nice, but the important thing is what is best for the community, not the ego of the answerer.